# Does Java EE transaction timeout interrupt method execution?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, timeout, jta

If the transaction times out during method execution, how does the container handle the current stack frame according to the Java EE spec?

- Does the method execution continue till return
- Or does the container interrupt the method execution, returning immediately

Of course, in either case a rollback would be performed after returning. But which is the correct behavior?

Comment: Could you please clarify "transactional method times out"? Do you mean "transaction times out during method execution"? Or something else?

Comment: @Tuomas Toivonen It was about 3 years ago when I used CMT transactions for the last time, but if I remember it right (for the WebSphere 7.5 EJB container) - for an example: if we set the TX timeout equals to 60 seconds and run a method, calling some external system and this call will last longer than 60 seconds, then after 60 seconds no timeout exception will be thrown and the method execution will not be interrupted. Container will wait until the method finishes and throw the timeout exception after.